# Is there any kernel defined for simplex domain (i.e. probability vector)?

Tags: probability, kernel-trick, dirichlet-distribution

I am wondering **if there is any kernel function that is specifically designed for simplex domain.**

By "**simplex domain**," I mean a set whose elements are probability vectors.
For example, 3-D simplex may refer to a set of all possible 3-D probability vectors, such as [0.1, 0.8, 0.1] and [0., 0., 1.]. All elements are nonnegative, and summed to one.

My inputs('x' part of data) are constrained to be a probability vector, and I want to try tailor-made kernel if there is one.

Or alternatively, is it okay to use widely used kernels such as RBF or Laplacian despite of the constraint?

Comment: Looking at the answers, there appears to be some confusion regarding what you mean by "kernel". What definition of "kernel" are you using?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant "kernel" in a machine learning sense. Ones that are positive semidefinite and can be decomposed into a inner product of  high dimensional mapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a look at the [information diffusion kernel](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2216-information-diffusion-kernels.pdf) which corresponds to a mapping from the simplex to the sphere (and uses the geodesic distance on the sphere to measure similarity).

Comment: This is quite creative, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) is defined on the n-simplex. You can use its PDF as a kernel if I understand your use of kernel correctly (its quite a loaded term).

Comment: I think that OP is referring to a function $K(x,y)$ that is symmetric $K(x,y)=K(y,x)$ and positive semidefinite. I don't think that the Dirichlet distribution satisfies this.

Comment: Sorry, I was using this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Definition). As I said the word "Kernel" is probably the most overused and abused term.

Comment: @bdeonovic even though, using the kernel definition from KDE, Dirichlet distribution in general does not satisfy symmetry condition $K(u) = K(-u)$